# json_encode / decode char troubles

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, json

I'm having some troubles with the json_encode/decode functions when i store the string to a MySQL DB table. 
The problem is in the swedish chars, like ÅÄÖ.
If have something like

```
$my_arr = array('Räksmörgås');
$json = json_encode($my_arr):
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

It works just fine, the trouble is, as i said, when i store the jsonstring to the db and then collects them. The table (entire db) has the encoding 'utf8_general_ci'. I've tried uft8_unicode_ci' as well, with the same result, that the output will be '`Ru00e4ksmu00f6rgu00e5s`'. The column where i store this valus is 'TEXT'.

What am i doing wrong?

Edit, i forgot to mention this is a plugin for wordpress and i'm using $wpdb->prepare() and $wpdb->query().

Comment: Make sure the connection to your database is configured as UTF8. E.g. `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you are stripping slashes.

```
// text: Räksmörgås
// json_encode(): R\u00e4ksm\u00f6rg\u00e5s
// your output: Ru00e4ksmu00f6rgu00e5s
```

Comment: Hmm. You're right. As i remember json_encode makes it with back-slashes, but the string to the database strips them out! Did not even see this. So, it's something with the $wpdb->prepare i guess.

Comment: Yep! when i manually add the back-slash with phpmyadmin the output is correct!

Comment: Then your insert is not correct, there is some `stripslashes()` on insert.

Comment: i did it like this: str_replace('\\', '\\\\', json_encode($my_arr)); and that works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to store result in `BLOB` and not `TEXT` field.
What do you used to store data ? PDO ? Mysqli ? Mysql ?

Comment: Actually, it's a plugin for wordpress. So i use $wpdb->prepare() and $wpdb->query(). I'll try blob!